# Typo3 flux - page configuration produces error on child-pages

Tags: typo3

I have a flux-backend layout that looks like this:

```
<f:section name="Configuration">
        <flux:form id="cugPageWithSidebar">
            <!-- Insert fields, sheets, grid, form section objects etc. here, in this flux:form tag -->
            <flux:field.checkbox inherit="0" inheritEmpty="0" name="settings.show_filter_selection" />
            <flux:grid>
                <!-- Edit this grid to change the "backend layout" structure -->
                <flux:grid.row>
                    <flux:grid.column colPos="0" colspan="3" style="width: 70%;" name="content" label="Main Content"/>
                    <flux:grid.column colPos="1" colspan="1" style="width: 30%;" name="sidebar" label="Sidebar (Menu)"/>
                </flux:grid.row>

            </flux:grid>
        </flux:form>
    </f:section>
```

I set the backend-layout to «Columns from selected "Page Layout" [flux__grid]» for the root page and the sub-pages.

When I try to edit a child page, I get a PHP Warning:

Core: Error handler (BE): PHP Warning: Undefined array key "settings.show_filter_selection" in /var/www/html/public/typo3conf/ext/flux/Classes/Provider/PageProvider.php line 402

I tried to set inherit and inheritEmpty to true with the same result.

I had to set T3 debugging to «live», otherwise this warning breaks the backend-editor.

With set to live, I can edit the pages just fine and I can also set the `show_filter_selection` setting. However, it looks ugly and I'd really like to get rid of that warning (also, because I'd like to set debugging to «Debug» in my development environment.

Typo3 11.5.27, Flux 9.7.2